# "Heat map" of average values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am looking to make a "heat map" where the color in the bin is the average of some 3rd value in each bin. For example, x and y position and then average elevation. My problem is that the scatter points and the boxes don't always overlap (upper left corner). Am I just missing something simple? Is there a better way?

Here is some working example code which illustrates my problem. Using Ipython --pylab

```
from scipy import stats
x=randint(0,50,60 )
y=randint(0,65,60 )
z=randint(0,20,60)
d = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x, y, z)
extent = [d[1][0], d[1][-1], d[2][0], d[2][-1]]
imshow(d[0], cmap='RdBu_r', extent=extent, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
scatter(x, y, s=50, c='0.8', edgecolor='0.8')
```

The output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx4iT.png

Answer (score 2):

I observed that x- and y- diretion in `d[0]` is flipped. It may be a problem with `imshow`. So just take the transpose (notice `d[0].T` in `imshow`)...

```
from scipy import stats

x=randint(0,50,60 )
y=randint(0,65,60 )
z=randint(0,20,60)
d = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x, y, z, statistic='mean')
extent = [d[1][0], d[1][-1], d[2][0], d[2][-1]]
imshow(d[0].T, cmap='RdBu_r', extent=extent, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
scatter(x,y, s=50, c=z, edgecolor='0.8')
```

Also, I changed the fourth argument of `scatter` to `c=z` so that you can see the actual values of the scatter points.